# Apex test Class - System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

The test class is as follows:
 I am trying to set the RecordType.Name in the test class but it gives me the message **"System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
class.TestAcctHierWarnDisplay.tstWarningDisplay1: line 45, column 3 External entry point".** The record types exist. 
I am not sure what I am missing.
 Gets the exception at
 **myacct.RecordType.Name = 'Master Account';**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide the necessary details to diagnose the problem. Seeing the code is necessary for that.

Comment: It seems light but there is actually enough information here if you're familiar with the platform.

Answer (score 5):

You should set the record type by ID, not by name:

```
id idRT = [select Id from RecordType where SobjectType = 'Account' and DeveloperName = 'RTDevName].Id; 

Account sAcct = new Account();
sAcct.RecordTypeId = idRT;
```

Also, note that I'm using developer name, this is the equivalent of the API name on object fields, the idea being that the actual name is a label and could be changed for frontend purposes.

FYI:
The reason you're getting an exception is because the account is not assigned a record type at this stage, so `myacct.RecordType` is `null`, which you're trying to dereference when accessing the `Name` field on it.